# ffmpeg Unrecognized option 'var_stream_map'

Tags: ffmpeg

I try:

```
ffmpeg -re -i ./2898654.mp4 -b:a:0 32k -b:a:1 64k -b:v:0 1000k -b:v:1 3000k  \
  -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 0:v -f hls \
  -var_stream_map "a:0,agroup:aud_low a:1,agroup:aud_high v:0,agroup:aud_low v:1,agroup:aud_high" \
  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
  ./out_%v.m3u8
```

error info:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2-1~16.04.york0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0.2' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Unrecognized option 'var_stream_map'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old.

The `-var_stream_map` option was added on 2017-11-20 in commit 92a32d0, but the FFmpeg 3.4 release was created on 2017-10-11. New features are not added to releases, so that is why 3.4.2 also does not include this option.

You can [download a recent `ffmpeg` version](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) from the git master branch, or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: thank you very much，I use  "download a recent ffmpeg version". thank you again ！！！

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg has stopped maintaining the builds after version 3 on apt repo. They moved to snap. So, doing `sudo apt install ffmpeg` will install a version 3.x.x. It was `ffmpeg version 3.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers` for my case as I write this answer.

I could not use snap too because I was using Ubuntu over wsl. When I tried the snap command, I got this:

```
$ sudo snap install ffmpeg
Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux.
This command has been left available for documentation purposes only.
```

The only option was to just download the binary from their releases page and manually rename and move to /usr/bin/.

```
$ wget https://github.com/eugeneware/ffmpeg-static/releases/download/b4.4.1/linux-x64
$ sudo mv linux-x64 /usr/bin/ffmpeg
$ chmod +x /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

After this, I was able to call ffmpeg

```
$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 4.4.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```