# installing and finding a path to chrome binary on linux machine which located at firebase servers

Tags: javascript, firebase, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to install a chrome binary, on a server which located at firebase server;
but, I don't really know where I can install it,

so I've try a couple of ways , first, by using the google cloud shell,
I manage to install it using those command on the cloud shell:
from the google cloud shell

```
   myusername@cloudshell:~
```

first the download:

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

then, the installation :

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

its a good place to say that, I have no idea, where this installation take place, and I don't know if my firebase project even 'know' about this..

but it worth a try, so in my index.js file , I have a function that supposes to go to the 'path' in which this installation was done, according to the the info I found in the web, its supposed to be at:

[image]

and so tried my luck and give this path to my function :

[image]

this lead to an error in the firebase logs, that tells me that the binary
is no where to be found in the given path:

[image]

so, this lead me to ask a couple questions:

1. can I navigate to my firebase project from the google cloud shell?, and then install there the chrome binary? in which folder that I choose to? , or even do more things, like installing packages etc, iike is was my local machine?
2. my general idea is to run a selenium web driver, on the firebase servers, is that possible?

Comment: The common way to do this is through puppeteer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732991/possible-to-run-headless-chrome-chromium-in-a-google-cloud-function and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=use+chrome+in+cloud+functions

Comment: I have posted an answer  instead of the comment expecting it can help other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to do this using Cloud functions, at this moment you cannot install any custom software, as already discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665954). As an alternative, the answer offers using Google App Engine to process heavy work. I would suggest making another question with the reason why you want to install Chrome or use it with your Cloud function. Maybe that would give better results, as the only options I see are following Frank’s commented question with headless Chrome or using GAE.